# Substitution Theorem of Conditional Probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability

Update: I think I have more or less answered my own question. I needed to model more closely on the theorem for expectations and specify the discrete case. Independence is a separate extension.

The Substitution Theorem for Conditional Probabilities, following the model given by the Substitution Theorem for Conditional Expectations, is given by

If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables then 
 $Pr\left( g(X,Y) = a \big| \; Y=y\right) =  Pr\left( g(X, y)= a  \big| \; Y=y\right)$

Proof:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables

$Pr\left( g(X,Y)= a  \big| \; Y=y\right) = Pr\left( g(X,Y) = a, Y=y \big| Y=y\right) \\
= Pr\left( g(X,y) = a \big| Y=y\right) \text{, for all } a. \square$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, 
$Pr\left( g(X,y) = a \big| Y=y\right)
= \frac{Pr\left( g(X,y) = a,Y=y \right)}{Pr\left(Y=y \right)}
= \frac{Pr\left( g(X,y) = a \right) Pr\left(Y=y \right)}{Pr\left(Y=y \right)}
= Pr\left( g(X,y) = a \right)$

cf. the Substitution Theorem for Conditional Expectations which is given by: $E(g(X,Y) |Y=y)= E(g(X,y) \big| \; Y=y)$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent,  $E(g(X,y) |Y=y)= E(g(X,y))$

Comment: Can you give an example where the rule _does not hold_ for _dependent_ random variables? That is, is the condition that $X$ and $Y$ be independent absolutely necessary for the conclusion to hold?

Comment: I do not understand the notations $P\left( g(X,Y) \big| \; Y=y\right) $ and $  P\left( g(X, y) \right)$.

Comment: @ Xi'an $g(X, Y)$ is just some function of $X$ and $Y$ and $g(X,y)$ can be thought of as just a function of $X$, like a marginal pdf, where $y$ is fixed and can be ignored.

Comment: @Dilip No example yet, but a good idea I'll think about. I think it will need independence, and I am happy for any proof that finds this necessary.

Comment: I suspect what @Xi'an is hinting at concerns what you mean by "$P$".  Evidently that's intended to refer to a "probability" (or maybe a probability density?), but as such its argument would have to be an *event*.  It's not at all clear what event something like "$g(X,Y)\mid Y=y$" is trying to describe.

Comment: Thanks to whuber for the translation! P has no meaning per se it depends which probability model you consider.

Comment: With the new formulation, this is exactly equivalent to the "Substitution Rule/Theorem for Conditional Expectations" since the probability of the event is the expectation of the indicator of the event.

Comment: Interesting that you suggest Blitzstein's Bridge but I am not sure how that would go.

Comment: Now that the question is clear, I would direct you to researching ["taking out what is known"](https://www.google.com/search?q=conditional+probability+%22taking+out+what+is+known%22).